# Adjusting wallpaper to make it fit netbook screen in Windows 7 Starter

Tags: windows-7, desktop, netbook, desktop-customization

I have a netbook with Windows 7 Starter.

I was trying to change the wallpaper, and found an application (John's Background Switcher) which said that I can make slideshows of themes - I assume similar to how you set the wallpaper in Windows 7 Ultimate.

The default wallpaper was still fine until downloading that application. After trying it, an error occurred and I couldnt change the background, so I closed the application. However the default wallpaper then changed its size; the central image dropped out of screen and I can only see a part of it in the bottom right hand corner.

I tried to adjust the image into the center, but it didn't work when I right click on desktop -> Graphic option -> panel fit -> "center image".

How can I adjust it back to normal as before?

Answer (score 1):

My windows 7 has an option for "Fill", but I don't have starter edition so yours might vary somewhat.  On XP it was called "Stretch".

Either way, I never use either option.  I always open my background in an editor like Paint.Net and resize it to match my actual screen resolution.  Then I save it as a bmp and set that bmp as my wallpaper.  It takes up more disk space that way, but I save making the operating system convert it to bmp for display.

Comment: Neeerdy. =) (15 char)